# Upgrade ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10 from CD not work

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

I have tried to upgrade from the CD and by mounting the .ISO. However, all have been unsuccessfull.

I have downloaded the 32 bit version of 9.10.

I have tried to follow the instructions from this website
http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading

First I tried to mount the ubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso
using the following:

```
sudo mount -o loop ~/Desktop/ubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386.iso /media/cdrom0
```

Which mounted it. But I never got the dialog box that says 'run upgrade'

I then did 'Alt F2' and typed the following:

```
gksu "sh /cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```

Still nothing happened.

I can browse the files from the mounted *.iso and on the burnt CD. However, the dialog doesn't appear.

I can boot from the CD if I restart my computer. However, I just want to do a upgrade and not clean install.

I can't do an upgrade from the update-manager as my Internet is too slow and unreliable.

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: Did you try burning the ISO to cd and insert it into your cdrom instead of mounting the ISO directly? That should auto-mount the cd and pop up the upgrade dialog automatically.

Comment: Your gksu cmd is wrong. Correct syntax is: `gksu "sh /media/cdrom0/cdromupgrade"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mentioned in the upgrade instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading#Upgrading%20Using%20the%20Alternate%20CD/DVD), you need the *alternate* CD, ubuntu-9.10-alternate-i386.iso, to do the upgrade. Confusing, I know, but that's the way it works.

Here's a BitTorrent link: http://releases.ubuntu.com/9.10/ubuntu-9.10-alternate-i386.iso.torrent

You can also go to the download mirror listing at http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/downloadmirrors#mirrors and get it from there instead.

Comment: I think you are right. I was thinking that the version I downloaded was able to start the upgrade. I didn't see anything to suggest that I have to download another iso. Thanks.